# Right column content overflowing over my footer

Tags: html, css, css-float

I know this has got something to do with a float, but I cannot seem to figure out where I am going wrong with this.

Please check this page for me, the content in the right column is flowing over my footer.

http://sun-eng.sixfoot.co.za/index.php?option=com_weblinks&view=categories&Itemid=48

Thanks!
James

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're setting the height explicitly in this rule, line 260 of layout.css:

```
.rightCol ul.latestnews {
  height:190px;
}
```

Just remove the height and you're good.

Comment: Crap a dog! I was looking for an explicit height! Thanks mate, overlooked it ;)